# How to render a React component styled with Emotion in an iframe in Gatsby site?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, iframe, gatsby, emotion

I work on a component library and a demo site.

Components are styled using [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/) and the demo site is built with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/).

For preview purposes, I'd like to render components in an iframe. This will ensure that styles from the website are not cascading to the components, make it easier to deal with responsive layouts, etc.

I'd also like to preserve hot-reloading inside the iframe.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-jw5u5), you can see an example of how `line-height` from the website is cascading to the `Button` component causing it to be very tall.

[image]

How could I render the `Button` with all its styles inside the iframe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the issue here is applying the style generated by `emotion` to the button placed inside the iframe.

I found this excellent example by Mitchell (emotion core team) that does exactly what you need: [github](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/760#issuecomment-404353706)

Here's a fork of your codesandbox with the code copied over, with a rudimentary homemade `<Iframe>` element: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-w0bsy)

[image: result]

Here's the relevant code:

```js
// src/components/Iframe.js

import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'

import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/core'
import createCache from '@emotion/cache'
import weakMemoize from '@emotion/weak-memoize'

// literally copied from Mitchell's codesandbox
// https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/760#issuecomment-404353706
let memoizedCreateCacheWithContainer = weakMemoize(container => {
  let newCache = createCache({ container });
  return newCache;
});


/* render Emotion style to iframe's head element */
function EmotionProvider({ children, $head }) {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={memoizedCreateCacheWithContainer($head)}>
      {children}
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}

/* hack-ish: force iframe to update */
function useForceUpdate(){
  const [_, setValue] = useState()
  return () => setValue(0)
}

/* rudimentary Iframe component with Portal */
export function Iframe({ children, ...props }) {
  const iFrameRef = useRef(null)
  const [$iFrameBody, setIframeBody] = useState(null)
  const [$iFrameHead, setIframeHead] = useState(null)
  const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate()

  useEffect(function(){
    if (!iFrameRef.current) return

    const $iframe = iFrameRef.current
    $iframe.addEventListener('load', onLoad)

    function onLoad() {
      // TODO can probably attach these to ref itself?
      setIframeBody($iframe.contentDocument.body)
      setIframeHead($iframe.contentDocument.head)

      // force update, otherwise portal children won't show up
      forceUpdate()
    }

    return function() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
      $iframe.removeEventListener('load', onload)
    }
  })

  return (<iframe {...props} title="s" ref={iFrameRef}>
      {$iFrameBody && $iFrameHead && createPortal((
        <EmotionProvider $head={$iFrameHead}>{children}</EmotionProvider>
      ), $iFrameBody)}
    </iframe>)
}
```

---

This needs more work if you want your iFrames to be pre-rendered during `gatsby build`.

For `styled-components` users, I found this snippet by [Stephen Haney](http://stephenhaney.com/using-styled-components-iframes-react/) that looks much more elegant than `emotion`:

> [...] `styled-components` includes a StyleSheetManager component that
>   can take a target prop. The target expects a DOM node, and it will
>   attach its dynamically created stylesheets to that node.
>
> `react-frame-component` uses React’s new version of its Context API to
>   expose a `FrameContextProvider`. It includes the `IFrame` document and
>   window in the context.
>
> You can combine these two APIs as follows to use `styled-components`
>   inside your IFrames:
>
> ```
>     {
>       frameContext => (
>         <StyleSheetManager target={frameContext.document.head}>
>           <React.Fragment>
>             {/* your children here */}
>           </React.Fragment>
>         </StyleSheetManager>
>       )
>     }   </FrameContextConsumer> </Frame>
> ```
>
> This works perfectly with react v16.4.1, styled-components v3.3.3, and react-frame-component v4.0.0.

Comment: Thanks @Derek for digging this. I tried to run your codesandbox, but the iframe body is not showing up. I tried to add console logs and it looks like `onLoad` is never called (even though the event listener is attached). I wonder whether it's some kind of browser quirk or a timeout issue. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hi Misha, the demo works in latest version of Chrome & Firefox (tried again just now), I do wonder if it's a finicky timeout thing. I might try to make a local build later, as I find codesandbox unreliable at times

Comment: @DerekNguyen, have you tried your solution with gatsby build?

Answer (score 0):

i [forked](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-default-sxqmd) your sandbox to show a solution.
Steps:

1. Use or write a component for iframe. In sandbox i use `react-frame-component` (https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component). It will render iframe with any passed content for us.
2. Find a way to get styles created by emotion. Emotion just creates `style` nodes so we just will copy it. In sandbox i wrote very primitive code just to check this idea and it is working, but in production you should write something more advanced i think:

```
        <Frame>
          <FrameContextConsumer>
            {// Callback is invoked with iframe's window and document instances
            ({ document }) => {
              if (isFirstRender) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  // find styles in main document
                  const styles = Array.from(
                    window.document.head.querySelectorAll("style[data-emotion]")
                  )
                  // and add it to the child
                  styles.forEach(s =>
                    document.head.appendChild(s.cloneNode(true))
                  )
                  isFirstRender = false
                }, 100)
              }
              // Render Children
              return <Button>Primary</Button>
            }}
          </FrameContextConsumer>
        </Frame>
```

Note: i am not familar with `emotion` but i think it will not create `style` nodes in production (via webpack ofc), but will create a file, something like `styles.css`. 
Then you should add link to it to the child document:

```
              if (isFirstRender) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  const link = document.createElement("link");
                  link.href = "styles.scss";
                  link.rel = "stylesheet";

                  document.head.appendChild(link);

                  isFirstRender = false
                }, 100)
              }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Copying styles manually feels very hacky. I wonder whether there is a better way to generate the HTML including the styles, e.g. using `html-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko `html-webpack-plugin` will not help here, because it works in the build phase, but `iframe` will be created in runtime. I will try to find another solution.

Comment: Why the `iframe` can't be created at build time?

Comment: AFAIK iframe can be create at build time in modern browser by using [srcdoc](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcdoc). I think it's possible to render the component to string during build, but I'm not sure how it'll be rehydrated on client side